# Laravel 8 Route in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following web routes in my Laravel project

```
Route::resource('client/{client}/users', UserController::class);
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

For the latter I am able to use `{{ route('users.create') }}` in my blade file, but I'm not sure what to put for the other one.

I need to 2 ways separate resources because some users are able to edit users from their own client (/users) and users of other clients (/client/123/users)

`php artisan route:list shows that I'm getting the same name for both. What's the correct way to name the clients-users resource?

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | client/{client}/users             | users.index                     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                                       | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | POST      | client/{client}/users             | users.store                     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                                       | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | client/{client}/users/create      | users.create                    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                                      | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | client/{client}/users/{user}      | users.update                    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                                      | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | DELETE    | client/{client}/users/{user}      | users.destroy                   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                                     | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | client/{client}/users/{user}      | users.show                      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                                        | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | client/{client}/users/{user}/edit | users.edit                      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                                        | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
```

and

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | users                             | users.index                     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                                       | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/create                      | users.create                    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                                      | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | DELETE    | users/{user}                      | users.destroy                   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                                     | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users/{user}                      | users.update                    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                                      | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}                      | users.show                      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                                        | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}/edit                 | users.edit                      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                                        | web                                                       |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum                  |
|        |           |                                   |                                 |                                                                                 | Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified          |
```

Comment: just `php artisan route:list`, then you can see all the routes with name/URI/...

Comment: @DengSihan See my edit

Comment: Use a normal route for that. `Route::get('client/{client}/users', [UserController::class, 'clients'])->name('users.clients');` `{{ route('users.clients', ['client' => $client_id]); }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third arguement of the `resource` is an array of options, one of which allows you to specifiy a prefix.

```
Route::resource('client/{client}/users', UserController::class, ['as' => 'clients']);
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

Now your routes should be

```
clients.users.{action}
users.{action}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it a name. That said, I don't think you want `Route::resource` for that route.

I'm gonna give it the name `clients.users.index` but you can give it whatever name you want.

```php
Route::get('clients/{client}/users', [ClientController::class, 'users'])->name('clients.users.index');
```

```php
{{ route('clients.users.index') }}
```

The way to handle nested resources would be to declare the route:

```php
Route::resource('clients.users', SomeOtherController::class);
```